# How to fix error "TechTalk.SpecFlow.SpecFlowException: Unable to find plugin in the plugin search path: Blackbaud.UAT.SpecFlow.Selenium"?

Tags: c#, specflow

In spec flow for .cs file of feature file (generated by default), I'm getting this error:

> TechTalk.SpecFlow.SpecFlowException: Unable to find plugin in the plugin search path: Blackbaud.UAT.SpecFlow.Selenium

How to fix this error?

Comment: Hi guys, I got the solution of the above question:

Follow these steps, it will work:
1. open Visual Studio
2. Navigate to Tools>options.
3. Click on spec flow
4. In right side area, spec flow related information will appear.
5. Set "Appdomain" as the option for Code generation mode section.

It will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for this question (according to OPer, who posted this as a comment below the question ...):

> Follow these steps, it will work:
>
> 1. open Visual Studio
> 2. Navigate to Tools>options.
> 3. Click on spec flow
> 4. In right side area, spec flow related information will appear.
> 5. Set "Appdomain" as the option for Code generation mode section.

Credits: OPer ...